# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating camera.pictureSize)

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-ios, expo-camera

I am creating a react-native app to use the expo-camera module.

So I declared a camera variable as

```
let camera: any = null;
```

I am ***passing a reference to this*** from the ***return*** as:

```
<Camera style = {{flex: 1, opacity: camOpacity}}
          type = {state.type}
          ratio = "2:1"
          ref = {async (ref) => (camera = ref)}>
```

But when I run the app, it starts normally but on trying to take a picture it gives the error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'camera.pictureSize')]
```

This error is occuring from :

```
console.log(camera.pictureSize);
```

But it is also happening at:

```
console.log(" --> Taking image");
    const opts = {
       skipProcessing: true,
       exif: false,
       quality: 0
    };
    let photo = await camera.takePictureAsync(opts);
```

from the **camera.takePictureAsync(opts)** part when I am **commenting out the console.log(camera.pictureSize);**

For some reason the reference isn't getting detected maybe.

My package.json is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-2d-context": "0.0.2",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-camera": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-gl": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "~12.1.0",
    "mem": "^8.0.0",
    "@unimodules/core": "~5.5.0"
  }
```

I read there were some such errors in the current expo-camera release, but even if I downgrade the packages and dependencies it is still being persistent.

Any help would be really appreciated.

### EDIT:

```
const photo = async (): Promise<CameraCapturedPicture> | undefined  => {
      if(camera){
        console.log(" --> Taking image");
        const opts = {
          skipProcessing: true,
          exif: false,
          quality: 0
        };
        return await camera.takePictureAsync(opts);
      }
    }
    
    console.log(" --> Resizing image");
    const {uri} = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      photo.uri,
      [
        { resize: {width: 256, height: 512}},
        { crop: {originX: 0, originY: 128, width: 256, height: 256}}
      ]
    );
```

I changed the code according to Linda's kind suggestion but now the error is that the Promise is not a valid type and **photo.uri** doesnt have the *uri* property

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the `camera` ref object to `null`. So before you call any functions on it, you need to verify that it has actually been set to a `Camera` and is not still `null`. I suspect that's the cause of the error in your take picture function.  Notice [in the docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#methods) that they check `if (this.camera) {` before calling a method on the camera.

`console.log(camera.pictureSize)` is just wrong even when camera is not `null` because that property doesn't exist.  `pictureSize` is a prop which you pass to the `Camera` component.  It is not a property which exists on the camera instance.  You should [review the documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#picturesize).

Rather than using `any`, you can change your variable declaration to be `Camera | null` and that should help you to see the properties and methods which are available.

```
let camera: Camera | null = null;
```

You can check that `camera` isn't `null` inside the method that you call to take a picture:

```
const takePicture = async (): Promise<CameraCapturedPicture> | undefined => {
  if (camera) {
    console.log(" --> Taking image");
    const opts = {
      skipProcessing: true,
      exif: false,
      quality: 0
    };
    return await camera.takePictureAsync(opts);
  }
};
```

Or you can check before calling the method and pass the `camera` variable into the method so that typescript knows it's not `null`.

```
const executeTakePicture = async (cam: Camera): Promise<CameraCapturedPicture> => {
  console.log(" --> Taking image");
  const opts = {
    skipProcessing: true,
    exif: false,
    quality: 0
  };
  return await cam.takePictureAsync(opts);
};

const maybeTakePicture = async (): Promise<CameraCapturedPicture> | undefined => {
  if (camera) {
    return await executeTakePicture(camera);
  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: It says that Promise<CameraCapturedPicture> | undefined is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because if doesnt refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.
And then later I was using ImageManipulator to resize the image and it says property uri doesnt exist on t